# Key re-mapping or how get HEX for button

Tags: macos, keyboard

i have new macbook air  13". There is "><" button under Esc. I want to rebind this button to semicolon ";". How? Or please tell me, how can I find Hex for this button, than I can change it by my self in defaultkeybinding.dict :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

DefaultKeyBinding.dict wouldn't work in a lot of applications, and `"<" = (insertText:, ";");` wouldn't change ⌘< to ⌘;.

You could try using KeyRemap4MacBook and saving this as [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<item>
<name>test</name>
<identifier>private.test</identifier>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::BACKQUOTE, KeyCode::COMMA, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen>
</item>
</root>
```

[KeyCode::BACKQUOTE](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data) is the same key code as `<` on ISO keyboards.

The test folder has an [XML file](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml?raw=true) with all the predefined remappings.

Another option would be to create a keylayout file with [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele).